# Customize query in odm

Tags: jrules

I need to customize my query in brms such that all rules effective on a certain date should get fired.I have a ruleset variable as "current date" and "effective start date" variable in my decision table.
I need to customize my query such that whenever "current date=some date" it should check the effective date for all rules and fire the rules which are true.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a pre-condition on the decision table which does the check if the  effective start date is equal to or after the current date.

Comment: need to use custom query with help of already defined ruleset variables

Answer (score 0):

How about a query such as:

```
Find all decision tables such that each decision table uses the value of the current date of the session and the effective date of each decision table is before or the same as the current date of the session
```

Comment: ur correct ..this can be done...but I need to do it with customize query.I Am stuck as how to use ruleset variable in extender class for customize query